# OpenCV simple code compiles successfully but crashes on runtime

Tags: c++, qt, crash, segmentation-fault, opencv3.0

My goal is to run a simple OpenCV contribute (extra) module in Qt 5.5.1.

Steps:

1) created a Qt Application app;

2) changed the `main.cpp` file to :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    qDebug() <<"start!" << endl;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    string trackingAlg = "KCF";
    MultiTracker trackers(trackingAlg);

    qDebug() <<"success!" << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

and here is my `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = tracker4

CONFIG += c++11

TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv

LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --libs`
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_tracking
```

The program compiles successfully, but in the runtime, it crashes without even running the `main()` function. I don't get such an error when I run this in Code::Blocks but in Qt I still have this issue.

I am using Qt 5.5.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Can anyone generate this "seg fault" error in his/her machine?

Comment: I just noticed that the Qt Console Application with a very simple code containing `imshow("windowname", img)` also is crashed. Please note that other opencv functionality (like Mat type, imread, ...) work well.

Answer (score 0):

For QT 5, build the OpenCV with QT=OFF.
For QT 4, build the OpenCV with QT=ON.